# Why are there multiple Console Window Host open in the background?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, process

Why are there multiple Console Window Host open in the background?

[image: task manager with multiple windows console host]

For those that don't know, it's the command prompt running in the background but without a graphical user interface. Is it being used as an attack vector to run viruses on my computer that bypass the antivirus because the commands are being run by a Microsoft file?

Comment: You can use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to try and determine what applications are automatically being started when a user logs in. It will be difficult and nearly impossible to diagnose this issue without more information.  There is several explanations for this behavior that don't actually involve malware by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or a similar tool that would show the processes in a tree view. (Run it "As Administrator" for best results.) The Conhost process will always be shown as a child of the program that created the console.

> it's the command prompt running in the background but without a graphical user interface.

Not exactly. *Any* .exe file can be marked as "requires console" when it is compiled, and any such console-based program will cause a Conhost instance to be spawned – it could be cmd.exe, it could be PowerShell, it could be Python, it could be something entirely different.