# Windows Terminal Hosting

Tags: windows-terminal

How do you disable windows terminal hosting to stop receiving remote requests to windows terminal.
Not powershell Disable-PsRemoting -force

As an example I would like to disable access to SSH

Thanks

Comment: Please describe those “remote requests” in greater detail.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding or misinterpreting something you're seeing, and then the words you are using mean something different to us. Can you take a few steps backwards in your troubleshooting process and tell us more about these requests you're receiving. Clearly describe them, include any messages/text in them. Describe your computer environment, give us your OS and its version, and a general view of the software you use. Tell us about the research you have done prior to asking here. We need more information before we'll be able to understand the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "Windows Terminal hosting"; it's like asking to disable "Firefox hosting" for a website, because Windows Terminal doesn't receive any such requests – it's the app that *displays* command input/output, but it's not what actually processes them, and both SSH and PsRemoting do not involve Windows Terminal (or any other terminal) on the receiving-side at all.

To prevent incoming access via SSH, you need to disable the SSH service, depending on which one you have installed, *and/or* disable the Windows Firewall rules that allow the requests through. If you're using the built-in "OpenSSH for Windows", the service is named "OpenSSH Server" in services.msc.

Comment: Is it possible that it may be console hosting? Is there a difference between the terminal application and the console application?

Comment: @RussDuPreez it could be [console host](https://superuser.com/questions/1648598/why-are-there-multiple-console-window-host-open-in-the-background) but the answer is the same, find out where or how that console is being launched and stop that. If it is an SSH server you find and disable the SSH service running that console.

Comment: @Russ: Do you mean the "Conhost" process? It's slightly different, in that it serves both as the visible console *and* as handler for various "console output" functions even if the program is invisible. Basically, every console-based app automatically gets a Conhost process to accompany it. That doesn't mean Conhost is what's starting it – it's the opposite.